# What's the anatomy of a Bluemix/Cloud Foundry node red project?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, cloudant, node-red, watson

There's lots of documentation and a kludgy console to set up continuous deployment in Cloud Foundry, but I haven't found any documentation on what the artifacts inside a repository need to be.

I don't want to cut-n-paste flows from the node red editor.  If that's the only way, then IBM is not ready for prime time.  I also am aware of most everything about my flows being in the Cloudant nodered db.

A node red application is more than the flows though.  What about my _design docs for my dbs?

I need device info and other stuff from the Watson console, Cloudant info and my flows packaged up into something deployable.

Has anyone scripted this?

What I mean by this is I can clone a Docker project, an npm project and all sorts of projects that implement a build->test->push mechanism.  They employ a configuration script of some sort (e.g. package.json) and contain a bunch of source files for the actual application, test scripts, db scripts, whatever is necessary to deploy the application and its environment into a host.  I see lots of documentation on the toolchain and its features, but I'm not clear on if it's possible to make use of it for my hosted node red application.  Or if I have to write the scripting mechanisms to offload flow info from the nodered db and query all my other dbs for their respective _design docs and all the other configuration information required to set up an IoT node red application.

I forgot to mention, the copy/paste method loses information; you get no tab level metadata.  The only way to get all the flow stuff is to pull if from the nodered flow record.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node-RED will release a new version in a couple of days that will introduce projects, so you'll be able to use GitHub and all the usual tools to handle your app: https://twitter.com/NodeRED/status/956934949784956931 and https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/projects/

While it doesn't address your short-term needs, I think it's the best long-term solution. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I can wait a few days :)  Do you know if this will be available in IBM Cloud Foundry/Bluemix's environment?  I've done all my work directly in their consoles.  I hope that if I were to combine this with some scripting and bluemix/cf calls I could bundle up everything I need eventually.  I wonder if it's possible to get my device configs from Watson, too.

Comment: No, it will not be available in the cloud version. Can I suggest we have this discussion on the Node-RED mailing list, link on nodered.org, as it needs some discussion and not suited to a SO q&a